# Oracle Apex CARDS -- I want to have the card title in the page item when I click on the each card. (Cards type in Classic report)

Tags: oracle-apex

In classic report CARDS template, On clicking the card (not the link and just the card region) I want to read the same CARD_TITLE and store it into a PAGE_ITEM.

I have achieved it by making the CARD_TITLE as link and added dynamic action on it but i want to achieve it by clicking on the CARD.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEYQ8.png)

In the Image i have a classic report which is converted as cards. There are 7 seven cards in the page. meaning 7rows in the classic report.

I want to have the respective date  should be populated on summary_date field when i click on each card. Currently its populating all the dates  in the page item.

Thanks,
Raja P

Comment: Hi Raja, did you still need help with this? Did you see Scott's answer?

Comment: Hi Dan, I tried with the solution given by scott but i didnt get the expected result.

I am completely new to Apex and i didnt get proper tutorial for cards online. It will be great if you share some advanced tutorial for apex.

Comment: This behaviour sounds like either the selector is wrong (which works for me), or you're not utilising the this.triggeringElement concept. Perhaps mock up the example on apex.oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic action on click of jQuery selector, ensuring scope dynamic if your region refreshes, and maybe prefix with a static region ID if there are more than one set of cards.

```
.t-Card
```

Then have a JavaScript action in that DA that sets your item

```
$s('P1_ITEM', $(this.triggeringElement).find('.t-Card-title').text());
```

There will be a few variations on this.

For example, it could be a Set Value action that uses the second expression to populate yoru nominated field.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I tired with the solution you suggested but still need more accuracy. I have refined my question after changes applied you changes.

Comment: Can we have name for each cards (Each row in classic report) eg: we can have date in my example?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
full card action->redirect to URL:
javascript:apex.item( "P20_ID_SELECTED" ).setValue( "&ID.");